# Mapping inside a map function, while getting the data from the state a of parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When it goes to getDropDownOptions, I get this error - **Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**
I'm not using any componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate, neither setting state anywhere related to this functionality.
**rowInfo** is the Items inside an array, that Im mapping.
**allProducts** is the data I'm getting from a parent component.

````
    return (
      <SelectBox
        options={getDropdownOptions}
        value={{ label: '', value: '' }}
        onChange={e =>
          onItemChange({
            itemKey: headerItem.itemKey,
            arrayIndex: index,
            value: { label: e.value, value: e.value }
          })
        }
        customClass="lineItemDropdown"
      /> ```


const getDropdownOptions = () => {
    const dropDownOptions = allProducts.find(
      product => product.productId === rowInfo.productId
    ).packages;
    return dropDownOptions;
  };
````

Comment: Well, what _is_ `getDropdownOptions`?

Comment: Please provide some more context. What does the `onItemChange` function do here?

Comment: add code inside `getDropdownOptions`

Comment: Is your `SelectBox` component expecting `options` prop to be a function or an array?...right now, you're passing a reference to function

Comment: you are not calling `getDropdownOptions` in `options={getDropdownOptions}` to return and pass `options`

Comment: @GabrielMC , The SelectBox component here, expects an array. As Im passing a reference to a function which in turn returns an array, this should work right ? Correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: @PradeepSharma see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are passing a reference to a function for `options` instead of the value that the function returns.

Right now, if you were to `console.log(props.options)`, you would see a function....but you need an array.

So try this:

```
<SelectBox
  options={getDropdownOptions()}
  ...       
/>
```

OR, instead of using a function, just set a variable:

```
const dropDownOptions = allProducts.find(
      product => product.productId === rowInfo.productId
    ).packages;
    return dropDownOptions;

return (
   <SelectBox
     options={dropDownOptions}
     ...       
   />
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I've actually tried doing the same, it shows that same error "Maximum update depth exceeded". So instead of calling that function, if I just pass a reference or an arrow function, it says "options.reduce is not a function" - which means I'm not passing an array, I believe. But if I try creating that array outside and try to pass that variable, I'm getting that first error again.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason you're getting that error - probably something inside that component, but you still need to pass an array to `options` if that's what you're expecting